# Cannot access Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu [Tried: sudo update-grub, os-prober, and BootRepair]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

Disclaimer: My tech skills are limited. I can follow instructions found online, but I'm not a programmer.

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my PC, I can no longer access Windows 10: it does not show up in Grub. The Windows 10 partition is mounted and still accessible via nautilus. Please help.

EDIT 2: Someone asked me to paste a boot info summary from Boot Repair. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NwtqHv5Fkf/) it is. Thanks for replying.

**What I've Tried**

EDIT: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) did not help either, so, following the logic of that post, one of the following must be false:

1. That Windows is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
2. Ubuntu is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
3. You're currently seeing the grub menu at boot.

I am currently seeing the grub menu at boot. When I use the above solution, a menu option does appear in grub ('Windows (UEFI)'). Activating that options returns

```
error: no such device: /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.

Press any key to continue...
```

I've tried `sudo os-prober`, which returns

```
/dev/sda5:elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (0.4.1):elementary:linux
```

and `sudo update-grub`, which returns

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Found elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki (0.4.1) on /dev/sda5
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I've tried running Boot Repair's "Recommended repair" option, following the instructions and pasting things into the terminal. That didn't help.

I tried following the steps in [the answer to this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732747/after-installing-lubuntu-in-dual-boot-with-windows-10-i-cannot-access-windows-a), which had me fiddling with the `40_custom` file under `/etc/grub.d/`, trying to paste certain values that I got from running `sudo blkid`, which returns

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="98DC74BDDC74976A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cf469219-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="62FA7667FA76377F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cf469219-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="5852645F526443BA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cf469219-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="613bbe7f-5979-483b-a9f5-8f9451c17cb0" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cf469219-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="f1088132-e83e-41bb-8e66-451243ec4fbc" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cf469219-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="b8906912-62d7-465c-b672-77a38295c35e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cf469219-07"
/dev/sda8: UUID="DF4A-DF38" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="cf469219-08"
/dev/sda9: UUID="f8786617-7440-4a64-9699-6d4d3e1ad3a4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cf469219-09"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Ewok1" UUID="96F046F4F046DA5F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="6b53319e-01"
```

His steps involved pasting a script into the `40_custom` file (this script is reproduced in full below). The instructions were to then "Change UUID (SPX7ZJUBC2EN7FAH) and position ('hd0,msdos1') of Windows", presumably with the values obtained from `sudo blkid`.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

# Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
menuentry 'Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (loader) (/dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os 
$menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-SPX7ZJUBC2EN7FAH' {
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod ntfs
     set root='hd0,msdos1'
     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  SPX7ZJUBC2EN7FAH
 else
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root SPX7ZJUBC2EN7FAH
     fi
     parttool ${root} hidden-
     drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
     chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
   set timeout=10
fi
# End of Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

I pasted the UUID value for my `/dev/sda1/` partition, which I found using `sudo blkid`, but I could not determine what to replace 'hd0,msdos1' with. It did not work in the end: when updating grub, it still did not find Windows. (I also replaced part of the label for the boot entry, since I have Windows Home edition and not Pro, but I can't see why changing the labelling should cause the script to stop working).

**What I did when I installed Ubuntu**

I already had a Windows 10/elementaryOS dualboot. So the Ubuntu installer only detected elementaryOS to begin with. It asked me if I wanted to install Ubuntu alongside that. I thought, no. So I picked the 'Something else' option, downsized the ElementaryOS partition, and installed Ubuntu on the new partition.

This first attempt failed. I got an error message that, for unrelated reasons, I did not have time to look at closely. It was something like 'Cannot override grub. Installation will cancel', although the message was longer than that. I aborted, confirmed that I still had access to Windows (which I did), and shut down.

The next day, having more time on my hands, I wanted to replicate that error. So I did the same, only this time there was no error message. Ubuntu installed, and when I booted up, I could choose between Ubuntu and elementaryOS.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: You cannot have Windows booting in UEFI mode. It only boots from MBR/msdos (which you have) in BIOS boot mode. And UEFI and BIOS are not compatible, or once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other systems in same boot mode.  Windows 10 is also hibernated. And with BIOS/MBR the only way to turn it off is to temporarily install a Windows boot loader, fix Windows and then restore the BIOS version of grub or grub-pc.

Comment: @oldfred But prior to this, I could choose between Windows and elementaryOS via a grub menu.

Comment: That was because both were BIOS installs.